# Is std::vector<const int> undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, vector, constants

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t#6955332) I tried this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const int x = 5;
    // x = 200;           Not possible, of course.

    std::vector<const int> xVector = { 5 };
    xVector[0] = 200;

    std::cout << xVector[0];   // 200, no surprise.
}
```

This compiles in Visual Studio 2017. But is this behaviour undefined as in [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)?

Bonus questions: What are the technical reasons that a `std::vector<const int>` isn't just a vector of un-modifiable `int`s?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768089/vectorconst-int-is-not-allowed-why-is-pairconst-int-int-allowed) says that it's not allowed.

Comment: *"This compiles in Visual Studio 2017"* - Then it's either a bug or permissive flag in your project options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)

Comment: (compilers are required to compile correct code, but are not required to error (although they're expected to do so, especially with `-pedantic`) on incorrect code -- compiler specific extension is a thing)

Comment: By the way. MSVC on godbolt doesn't accept it https://godbolt.org/g/Y6qmjj

Comment: **NOT** a duplicate of the "is it allowed" question. This is more specific. The other question establishes it's not allowed, but it's either ill-formed or Undefined Behavior. Which of the two is not answered there, and asked here.