# A nonconst vector whose elements cannot change - alternatives

Tags: c++

I have this obsession with making things `const` that really should be `const`, even when it seems a bit painful to do so.

In this case, I want a `vector<int>` into which I can add elements, but whose existing elements I cannot change. The problem is that `vector<const int>` is not allowed.

The purpose is not only to prevent the users of my classes to modify things they shouldn't modify (this can be easily done by `const` iterators in member functions). It is also, just as importantly, so **I myself don't later do things in my own code that I didn't intend on doing**.

I have found two alternatives:

- Use `deque<const int>` instead.
- Create my own vector class that wraps the actual `vector`, like this (I do this for `int` here, but in reality I would use templates for generality)

  ```
  class my_vector {
  private:
    std::vector<int> vec;    
  public:
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator cbegin() { return vec.cbegin(); }
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator cend() { return vec.cend(); }
    void push_back(int i) { vec.push_back(i); }
  };
  ```

Which of these ideas (or others) would you recommend? Will the compiler turn the second alternative into code that is just as fast as using the vector directly?

Comment: You do understand that you could not do much with a `vector<const int>`, even if it was allowed, right? For example, you could not remove elements, and you could not sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your obsession is understandable and I do not disagree, but unless you have a really pressing *need* for it, the effort required might not be worth the effort.

Assuming you chose `vector` as your container based on your design requirement, I would not recommend changing it to `deque`, or any other type. It would only serve to confuse a future reader (which would likely be yourself), and is also a bad practice otherwise.

If we go with your wrapper solution, you would have to <strike>hide</strike> override all members which *could* modify the vector, which is a problem since there are a number of methods used to both access and modify, such as `operator[]`, `at()`, `front()`, `back()`. This could confuse a future reader, since they are used to the "standard" `vector` behavior.

By the way, are you sure `deque<const int> foo;` works? I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'
```

**Edit** It seems I didn't quite answer your question. If you *have* to pick one, I would choose the wrapper approach.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer private inheritance for these sort of standard-container-almost-exactly-fits-my-needs cases. Public inheritance leads to slicing or non-virtual destruction through a pointer to a base class. Composition requires too much extra typing.

Private inheritance and the use of `using` expresses your intent well.

Here is an exmaple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class my_vector : private std::vector<int> {
  // Utility type 
  typedef std::vector<int> base;
public:
  // Types I don't need to tweak:
  using base::value_type;
  using base::allocator_type;
  using base::size_type;
  using base::difference_type;
  using base::const_reference;
  using base::const_pointer;
  using base::const_iterator;
  using base::const_reverse_iterator;

  // Types I do need to tweak:
  typedef const_reference reference;
  typedef const_pointer pointer;
  typedef const_iterator iterator;
  typedef const_reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;

  // Constructors
    // Implicit constructors OK
  // Destructors
    // Implicit destructors OK
  // Assignment
    // Implicit assignment OK

  // Methods that I don't need to tweak:
  using base::assign;
  using base::get_allocator;
  using base::empty;
  using base::size;
  using base::max_size;
  using base::reserve;
  using base::capacity;
  using base::clear;
  using base::push_back;
  using base::pop_back;
  using base::swap;

  // Methods I need to tweak
  const_reference at( size_type pos ) const { return base::at(pos); }
  const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const { return base::operator[](pos); }
  const_reference front() const { return base::front(); }
  const_reference back() const { return base::back(); }
  const_iterator begin() const { return base::begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return base::end(); }
  const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return base::rbegin(); }
  const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return base::rend(); }

  // Methods I need to delete:
    // base::insert;
    // base::erase;
    // base::resize;

};

int main () {
  my_vector m;
  m.push_back(1);
  m.push_back(2);
  m.push_back(3);
  my_vector m2;
  m2 = m;
  std::copy(m2.begin(), m2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: I agree in general. For your particular code, it seems a bit pointless going to a lot of trouble to stop the user from assigning to an element, but to leave them with both `erase` and `insert` (which adds up to a slow way of achieving the same result). But it's for the questioner to specify the class and from that figure out what functions from `vector` to allow and what to forbid.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about the standard containers. If you need a container with characteristics that are different from those of the standard containers, write your own. If one of the standard containers is close to what you need, use that as the internal implementation. In short, `my_vector` is the way to go.