# STL containers and non copyable (and non movable) objects

Tags: c++, stl

Since STL containers require that all contents be copyable and assignable, what is the prefered idiom when working with non copyable objects?

I can think of two different approaches:

1. Store (smart) pointers rather than the objects in STL containers.
2. Get rid of STL containers and implement my own lists (e.g. each object must include a pointer to the next object).

Main drawback of the second approach is implementation of destructors (should the "next" object be destroyed before the current one in a recursive way?)

Comment: Of course it depends on the circumstances, but I would generally vote 1), if only because there is less to get wrong. Of course, you do then lose out on things like cache-friendliness of `std::vector`...

Comment: [Boost Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) is an implementation of 2)

Comment: `Since STL containers require that all contents be copyable and assignable` I thought moveability was sufficient nowadays? Assuming you really mean the standard library.

Comment: @BoBTFish that looks like the answer to me

Comment: *"Since STL containers require that all contents be copyable and assignable"* - No, they don't (if you mean the most recent C++ standard library).

Comment: No, I wasn't thinking of C++11 ;)

Comment: Boost has pointer containers too: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd choose approach #1: i.e. store *smart* pointers to objects in STL containers.

Note that it's fine to store non-owning raw pointers in STL containers (e.g. *observing* raw pointers), but storing *owning* raw pointers is a *"leaktrocity"*: use **`shared_ptr`** or new C++11's **`unique_ptr`** instead.

As for #2, writing your own containers from scratch requires lots of time and energy, and I believe you can't match the richness of a full commercial-quality STL library implementation in a reasonable time-frame.

Comment: I would like to see the term "leaktrocity" a bit more explained. Do you mean safety?

Comment: Well, I didn't mean implementing my own containers. I meant just implementing my own linked lists "in the C way". Anyway, first approach seems a better one.

Comment: @user1916893: It means that you have to use it very carefully to avoid memory leaks. You have to remember that the raw pointers own objects, and simply removing or replacing them will leak the owned object. Smart pointers manage the ownership explicitly, in a way that can be checked by the compiler; it's difficult to leak without making a conscious effort.

Comment: In additino to @MikeSeymour's wise note, with owning raw pointers there are problems also for _exception-safety_.

Answer (score 6):

> Since STL containers require that all contents be copyable and assignable, what is the prefered idiom when working with non copyable objects?

Well, actually with C++11 they require the object to be Movable. Only certain operations require them to be Assignable thanks to `emplace_*` methods.

> I can think of two different approaches:
>
> 1. Store (smart) pointers rather than the objects in STL containers.
> 2. Get rid of STL containers and implement my own lists (e.g. each object must include a pointer to the next object).

The two approaches are certainly feasible.

In C++11, the STL containers with `std::unique_ptr<YourObject>` elements in probably the best option. It's standard all the way down. There might be a *slight* performance issue with the node-based containers since the node and the element they point to will be distinct memory areas; but it's generally imperceptible.

If it is perceptible, or if you cannot use C++11, then you should learn about *intrusive containers*, which consist in augmenting your objects with hooks so that they can arrange themselves into lists, for example. There is a Boost library for this, obviously: [Boost.Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive.html).

> Non Movable you said ?

I would honestly challenge most of the designs that argue that an object should not be moved. The only issue with moving is linked to object identity and the potential issues of invalidating pointers to the object being moved from (and thus living dangling pointers behind). This can generally be solved by smart pointers and/or Factory approaches.

Comment: "I would honestly challenge most of the designs that argue that an object should not be moved." The most common case I see this in is for Thread objects whose running thread has captured the `*this` pointer.

Comment: @eatnumber1: Such a design tends to be brittle, though, as the slightest maintenance operation which leads to moving the object will break it. Hence my advice -- in the rest of the paragraph -- that if an object should not be moved, it is best to ensure so _structurally_, for example by putting it in a `std::unique_ptr`. Then the pointer can be moved, when the object remains stable.

Comment: unique_ptr makes it easy to work with an immovable object… which kind of makes my point that immovable objects are useful in some cases?